# How can evaluate some command without showing the result in the final document

Tags: spacing

I am looking for some command as `phantom` but without any effect in the final document. For example if I use `\phantom{afsdfasga}` it inserts a white box of the dimensions of `afsdfasga`. I want instead that nothing be produced but, if as argument of this command there are also other commands, I want them to be evaluated (without showing nothing in the final document).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\sbox0{ commands}
```

puts stuff in box 0 which will only appear if you use that box.